Unable to start cqlsh on because of Python 3.12.3, getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves'"
Virtual machine and docker not practical for my application because I need to be able to save the Cassandra database locally on a regular basis (incremental backup is true)
Does anyone have a workaround for downgrading to Python 3.11 when 3.12 is installed with the kernel for Ubuntu? There are several unmet dependencies when I try to downgrade (even if I try to completely uninstall) so I tried to do the quick and dirty sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python3 (I also tried with usr/bin/python3.11 /usr/bin/python3) only to receive the "No appropriate Python interpreter found." error when trying to start cqlsh.
So far it appears that the only option is to completely reinstall the kernel and somehow specify Python 3.11 when doing so before installing Cassandra again. This would be very tedious, especially if it does not guarantee that Cassandra will run locally. Ideas for other workarounds?
$:/apache-cassandra-4.1.5$ sudo ls /usr/bin/python*
 /usr/bin/python3  /usr/bin/python3.12
$:/apache-cassandra-4.1.5$ sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python3
$:/apache-cassandra-4.1.5$ sudo bin/cqlsh
No appropriate Python interpreter found.
$:/apache-cassandra-4.1.5$ sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.11 /usr/bin/python3
$:/apache-cassandra-4.1.5$ sudo bin/cqlsh
No appropriate Python interpreter found.
$:/apache-cassandra-4.1.5$ sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.12 /usr/bin/python3
$:/apache-cassandra-4.1.5$ sudo bin/cqlsh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apache-cassandra-4.1.5/bin/cqlsh.py", line 134, in <module>
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
  File "/apache-cassandra-4.1.5/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.25.0.zip/cassandra-driver-3.25.0/cassandra/cluster.py", line 33, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves'


the error message refers to a missing module six.moves.  what this installed or what is this ?

Why does needing to save the database locally stop you from using VM or Docker?

six.moves is apparently something having to do with Python version control. If you are insisting that Cassandra can only be run via VM or Docker, where does it say that in the Apache documentation? I have read several other answered questions here where people have had the same issue and I have tried all of their suggestions including using aptitude instead of apt-get to try to find solutions.

Nobody is saying that you need VM or Docker. But if they would solve the problem, why not use them?

This is a known issue with Python 3.12 that affects a lot of software. Python seems to introduce breaking changes in minor patch releases and Apache Cassandra is just one of the casualties.
The six module provides a compatibility layer that allows code to work with both Python 2 and Python 3 but appears to have been broken in Python 3.12. If you do a cursory internet search, you'll find a lot of reports from other software running into the same problem.
As a workaround, run cqlsh in a Python virtual environment virtualenv where Python 3.11 is installed.
For anyone interested, the Cassandra project is addressing this issue in CASSANDRA-19206. Cheers!
